# An internal error occurred during "Initializing Java Tooling." in Eclipse on startup

Tags: eclipse, startup

I am getting this strange error on startup. What could be wrong in my environment?

[image]

Here is the error :

```
>!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.jobs 4 2 2010-12-30 17:56:32.545
!MESSAGE An internal error occurred during: "Initializing Java Tooling".
!STACK 0
    org.eclipse.equinox.internal.provisional.frameworkadmin.FrameworkAdminRuntimeException: Not a file url: ../p2/
    at       org.eclipse.equinox.internal.frameworkadmin.equinox.EquinoxManipulatorImpl.loadWithoutFwPersistentData(EquinoxManipulatorImpl.java:368)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.frameworkadmin.equinox.EquinoxManipulatorImpl.load(EquinoxManipulatorImpl.java:331)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.core.target.AbstractBundleContainer.getVMArguments(AbstractBundleContainer.java:722)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.core.target.TargetPlatformService.newDefaultTargetDefinition(TargetPlatformService.java:493)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.core.PluginModelManager.initDefaultTargetPlatformDefinition(PluginModelManager.java:458)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.core.PluginModelManager.initializeTable(PluginModelManager.java:428)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.core.PluginModelManager.getWorkspaceModels(PluginModelManager.java:886)
    at org.eclipse.pde.core.plugin.PluginRegistry.getWorkspaceModels(PluginRegistry.java:176)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.core.SearchablePluginsManager.computeContainerClasspathEntries(SearchablePluginsManager.java:128)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.core.ExternalJavaSearchClasspathContainer.getClasspathEntries(ExternalJavaSearchClasspathContainer.java:29)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaProject.resolveClasspath(JavaProject.java:2584)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaProject.resolveClasspath(JavaProject.java:2679)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaProject.getResolvedClasspath(JavaProject.java:1866)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.core.JavaCore.initializeAfterLoad(JavaCore.java:3443)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.InitializeAfterLoadJob$RealJob.run(InitializeAfterLoadJob.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)
Caused by: java.net.URISyntaxException: Not a file url: ../p2/
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.frameworkadmin.equinox.utils.FileUtils.fromFileURL(FileUtils.java:192)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.frameworkadmin.equinox.EquinoxFwConfigFileParser.readp2DataArea(EquinoxFwConfigFileParser.java:362)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.frameworkadmin.equinox.EquinoxFwConfigFileParser.readFwConfig(EquinoxFwConfigFileParser.java:224)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.frameworkadmin.equinox.EquinoxManipulatorImpl.loadWithoutFwPersistentData(EquinoxManipulatorImpl.java:366)
```

Comment: Look at the bottom-left of the dialog window. There is a *Show Error Log* link, would you mind to click on that link and give us the content that is displayed?

Comment: And could you change the question name to something like: An internal error occurred during "Initializing Java Tooling."   That way the question will show up on Google searches if someone else has the same problem.

Comment: Copy here details, and relevant parts from workspace/.metadata/.log. Clearing .metadata/plugins/...resources/markers.snapshot often helps

Comment: Any resolution to this?  It would be helpful if you solved it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Eclipse internal error while initializing Java tooling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10892790/eclipse-internal-error-while-initializing-java-tooling)

Comment: @WundwinBorn, it's quite a feat for a question to duplicate another question asked a year and a half later!

Comment: @JohnK question still raising more than a decade :3

Answer (score 14):

Do not delete all the full .metadata

- Backup .metadata
- delete only .metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.project
- restart eclipse

Observation : the projects folders are created

Further - if you are using svn/git/hg have code repository links it would be destroyed, so to reinstate

- close eclipse
- copy relevant projects from backup to merge with current projects in .metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.project
- restart eclipse

Downfall - sporadic fail error may occur (sync or something) - harmless

Comment: Hi , Can you guys tell me why does this issue occurs and how this workaround helps solve the issue ?

Comment: My hunch - it's a cvs mutex lock on simlink, so unlinking and then relinking by removing the .lock file solves this  (I'd suggest steering away from eclipse to Intellij/Android Studio slowly - as support for eclipse might be on the decline)

Answer (score 3):

Deleting only .metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.project really helped me with my problem, that was just the same about Initializing Java Tool. Who have this problem should try this solution.

Answer (score 2):

OSX Eclipse Luna was hanging for me at the 30% mark of Initializing Java Tool. After a number of startups and force quit cycles I started eclipse from the command line:

/usr/local/eclipse-luna/eclipse --clean

Then closed eclipse and restarted from the taskbar and all OK
This resolved the problem for me

Answer (score 1):

If cleaning `.metadata` folder doesn't work for you there's another solution you might want to try. "Just close the eclipse and open it again". That worked for my eclipse-mars running on Windows 7 64 bit OS. I believe it will work for Android projects too which runs in eclipse environment.

Answer (score 1):

The answer from "raj" is ok, thank you men! it is correct.

In addition to his solution i have to comment. Please save a copy of your .metadata

Take care when you delete the folder: .metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.project

There is some folder called "RemoteSystemsTempFiles" and now you won't see the trouble when you start eclipse but you will other error when you close eclipse, because the folder "RemoteSystemsTempFiles" doesn't exist into .projects

So you will ned to copy your .metadataCOPIA/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.project/RemoteSystemsTempFiles   to  .metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.project/RemoteSystemsTempFiles

So, the quick fix to the error "“Initializing Java Tooling.” in Eclipse on startup" for me is:

1- Copy the folder ".metadata" of your workspace in a copy.
2- Delete the folder ".metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.project"
3- Close eclipse > You will get an error on closing eclipse.
4- Copy the folder .metadataCOPIA/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.project/RemoteSystemsTempFiles   to  .metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.project/RemoteSystemsTempFiles
5- Star Eclipse and all is ok.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but I still get this error in Luna.  A safe way to clear out the .projects folder is through the UI by deleting all projects without deleting from disk then importing them back into the workspace.