# Error launching eclipse : An internal error occured during initializing java tooling

Tags: java, eclipse

I get this error when I open the eclipse  ide :

```
Initializing java tooling has encountered a problem 
An internal error occured during initializing java tooling
```

I get this error with both  kepler and luna, does someone know what causes this error?

I've been trying for two days to solve it but I don´t really know the cause, since  I´m beginner with java development and eclipse environment.

If this can help, I use glassfish 3.1.

Comment: On which OS are you working ? Also, is your problem similar to this one : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4568297/an-internal-error-occurred-during-initializing-java-tooling-in-eclipse-on-sta ?

Comment: Try it from the command line if on linux to get more verbose output when an error happens.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when I opened a 47mega text file in Eclipse Luna. It seems that Eclipse is out of memory due to this file. I continued to get this error each time when I open Eclipse until I closed the 47mega text file IN Eclipse. If not, this file is opened each time when I open Eclipse. That's why I got this error.

Answer (score 0):

My project had plugin different of plugin installed on eclipse.

I resolved this problem with this solution. 
Example, my project with plugin tomcat-servlet-api.7.0, and on eclipse the server installed with tomcat version 8.5

The solution was refresh plugin of my project to version 8.5.