# An internal error occurred during: "Initializing Java Tooling". java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm getting an error `java.lang.NullPointerException`: "Initializing Java Tooling" soon as Eclipse IDE stated during
 have tried:

1. Deleted existing work space and restarted the IDE
2. CheckOut latest code and delete the previous one
3. Created a new work space
4. Changed the current working space directory

*Does it corrupt the existing code as well?*

Any ideas how to solve this problem?

Comment: Did you try solutions of other questions about the same topic? [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4568297/an-internal-error-occurred-during-initializing-java-tooling-in-eclipse-on-sta) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10892790/eclipse-internal-error-while-initializing-java-tooling)?

Comment: Do you have the stack trace from the workspace's .metadata\.log file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Eclipse internal error while initializing Java tooling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10892790/eclipse-internal-error-while-initializing-java-tooling)